IS it possible (and if so, how) to limit the number of times a MP4 file on a USB can be played, and also restrict the ability to copy the file?
My company has a number of videos which we "rent" out to clients. the majority of time, we use our web portal which gives them access for 72 hours, and allows a limited number of playbacks per credit. We have a client who is concerned about not having internet access during their meeting, and is requesting the video be available via USB.
Is it possible to limit what they can do with said video (number of times playing back, ability to copy/edit/send)? It does not have to be "high security"; as long as this would stop the layman, it does not need to stop an expert.
Thanks
I have tried searching the internet for this. Years ago we came up against this problem when switching from video tape to dvd, which is why we ultimately switched to web-hosted videos. I have still not found a solution.

You need to make an app (with code that limits the amount of plays). For your information... (1) Website code can be obfuscated (or even compiled into an EXE, if Windows is the end USB reader) and then your user can just run the html to see video controls. (2) Video file could be corrupted in a specific way where only the player knows how to fix & display it correctly. Outside of your player, the file is useless... I don't know how much you care to modify MP4 bytes or whether you're a coder, but try to investigate these options.

There IS a portable application that can be used to password-protect(and encrypt) single files such as MP4 video files. I am not sure if it has the one-time view capability, but check it out anyway:
VeraCrypt
Let me know if that works for you!
